# AngularJS configuring the persistence layer interaction

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have a very simple application which initially calls a php file to get data and then iterate through the dataset and create a table.  Within the table I have an "Enable/Disable" button which when clicked would update the model, which in turn would push to the persistence layer.  The issue I am running into is that while I am able to update the model which updates the view nicely, I am unable to figure out how to get the persistence layer part of it working.  I added two custom functions for the service "enable/disable" to reflect the button click event, but am not really sure if I am heading in the correct direction or not but my code is below.

The View partial:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Details</th><th>Facility</th><th>Last Login</th><th>Days from last login</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-class="{'error':user._accountDisabled,'success':user._accountDisabled==false}" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
                    <td>{{user._firstName}} {{user._lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user._userName}}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/userExceptions/{{user._userName}}">Details</a></td>
                    <td>{{user._facilityName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user._hrLastLogon}}</td>
                    <td>{{user._daysLastLogon}}</td>
                    <td>
            <ng-switch on="user._accountDisabled">
                <button ng-switch-when=true class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="enable(user)">Enable</button>
                <button ng-switch-when=false class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="disable(user)">Disable</button>
            </ng-switch>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The custom service for persistence:

```
angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('User', function($resource) {
return $resource('userActions.php', {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', params: {userName: 'userName'}, isArray: true},
    enable: {method: 'GET',params: {action: 'enable', userName: 'userName'}}},
    disable: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'disable', userName: 'userName'}}
});
});
```

Finally the controller:

```
function UserExceptionsCtrl($scope, User) {
$scope.users = User.query();
$scope.orderProp = '_firstName';

$scope.enable = function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.user._accountDisabled = false;
    $scope.user.$save();
    User.enable({userName:user._userName});
};
$scope.disable = function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.user._accountDisabled = true;
    $scope.user.$save();
    User.disable({action: 'disable', userName: self._userName});
};
}
```

*EDIT* As requested server side code:

The useractions file processes the request and creates mappers to retrieve a user object.  From the user object it updates the necessary property and saves it in the persistence layer.

userActions.php

```
$username = (isset($_REQUEST['userName']) ? $_REQUEST['userName'] : '');
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '');
require 'library/autoloader/src/autoload.php';
 try {
 $ADUserMapper = new UserMapper(new LDAPAdapter());
 switch ($action) {
case 'enable':
        $ADUserEditMapper = new UserMapper(new LDAPAdapter());
        $user = $ADUserEditMapper->findByUsername($username);
        if ($user) {
            $user->enableADAccount();
            $ADUserEditMapper->updateUAC($user);
        }
        break;
    case 'disable':
        $ADUserEditMapper = new UserMapper(new LDAPAdapter());
        $user = $ADUserEditMapper->findByUsername($username);
        if ($user) {
            $user->disableADAccount();
            $ADUserEditMapper->updateUAC($user);
        }
        break;
    default:
        $adapter = new PdoAdapter();
        $employeeDBMapper = new EmployeeMapper($adapter);
        $ADUsers = $ADUserMapper->findMultipleUsers(array('objectClass' => 'user'), "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com", TRUE);
        $exceptions = array();
        foreach ($ADUsers as $user) {
            $employee = $employeeDBMapper->findByUserName($user->userName);
            if (!$employee) {
                array_push($exceptions, $user);
            }
        }
        $result = array();
        foreach ($exceptions as $user) {
            array_push($result, $user->getExceptionData());
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        break;
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: Have you defined a POST method at /userActions.php on your php server to update your persistence layer? See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource most is convention over configuration, you need a REST API for it to work

Comment: No everything I have currently is written above, to update to the php file it does not need to be a post however does angular need that to push an update?

Comment: yes when you do $save() it's going to run an ajax POST to the route '/userActions.php'

Comment: Can you pass a custom field based on the current state? e.g. if button "Enable" is clicked when it saves post with action:'enable' and vice versa for disable?

Comment: You should put your server side code as well

Comment: So kinda new to this and apparently missed the memo about how json data is passed into the backend and I feel really dumb now...
I added
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $objData = json_decode($data);
and can now read all the data being passed into the php file.